# Fortify: How to get issue (vulnerability) list under a project using fortify rest api

Tags: fortify

I am trying to know the REST API for fetching all the vulnerabilities there in fortify website.
As like I can get the application details by hitting 'https://fortifyssc.xxx.com//api/v1/projects?q=id:"8731"'

Under this application there are so many issue list which is showing in fortify site. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC0vz.png)

How can I get the list of issues ( refer to attached image) under project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get issue list for particular project using this API: `[host:port]/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/[versionid]/issues`

Comment: can you please elaborate on what `versionid` is? Can you share a small hint for the users how to get the `versionid`?

Comment: You can get project versions using Get call  like "[host:port]/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions"